# Passport validity for entry into India

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, international-travel

Can an Indian passport holder (Indian citizen) enter India travelling from Australia with less than 6 months passport validity

Answer (score 1):

As you are an Indian citizen, you have the right to enter India at all times

You are under no requirements to have 6 months validity on your passport but **it must** still be valid

Now, if you are transiting somewhere and require entry to that country for some reason, this may have an impact, but for India proper, you will have no issues

Comment: Make sure passport is not expired. Otherwise, airline will refuse you to board.